# AVSpeechUtterance completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, onutterancecompleted

How do I set a completion event on the `SpeakUtterance(utterance)` function in Swift? I need this so that my speech is neither interrupted nor interrupting.

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked at the header (or generated Swift interface) for `AVSpeechSynthesizer`? Or its documentation? Looks pretty straightforward there...

1. Set an instance of one of your classes as the [`delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVSpeechSynthesizer/delegate) of the speech synthesizer.
2. In that class, implement the [`speechSynthesizer(_:didFinishSpeechUtterance:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate_Ref/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate/speechSynthesizer:didFinishSpeechUtterance:) method. It'll be called whenever an utterance finishes speaking.
3. There's no step three.